# Simplifying radical in Klein four group field extension

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to show that given a 4th degree irreducible polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}$)with a root $\alpha = \sqrt{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ then $\alpha$ can be expressed as $\alpha = \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$ if and only if the Galois group of $f$ is $V_4$.

I've managed to show that if $\alpha = \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$ then the Galois group is $V_4$ but I'm struggling with the other direction. I can see that if $G = V_4$ then there must be a quadratic subfield so that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) / \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{u}) / \mathbb{Q}$ and then we must have $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{u}, \sqrt{v})$ but can we then deduce from that that $\alpha = \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sqrt u + \sqrt v$ is fixed by none of the nonidentity automorphisms of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt u,\sqrt v)/\mathbb Q$, it can be contained in no proper subfield of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt u, \sqrt v)$, and so it is a primitive element for the extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ does that imply $\alpha = \sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$?

Comment: No, it does not. There will be infinitely many such $\alpha$, but $\sqrt u + \sqrt v$ is an easy one to write down.

Comment: But don't we need to show our particular $\alpha$ can be expressed as $\sqrt{u} + \sqrt{v}$?